# change() jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, switch-statement, onchange

I'm having some trouble getting my change() event working in jQuery. I am making a small program that converts temperatures to Kelvin, and I want the span that holds my value after conversion to update 1) every time the temperature to convert changes and 2) every time a different temperature scale is selected from the radio buttons.

Relevant Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=radio]').checkboxradio();
  var temp = parseFloat()
  $('input.listener').change(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    var val = $(this).val();

    switch (name) {
      case 'unit':
        var temperature = $('input#temp').val();
        switch (val) {
          case 'f':
            $('span#output').html(((temperature - 32) / 1.8) + 273.15);
            break;
          case 'c':
            $('span#output').html(temperature + 273.15);
            break;
          case 'r':
            $('span#output').html(temperature / 1.8);
            break;
        }
      case 'temp':
        var u = $('input[name=unit]:checked').val();
        switch (u) {
          case 'f':
            $('span#output').html(((val - 32) / 1.8) + 273.15);
            break;
          case 'c':
            $('span#output').html(val + 273.15);
            break;
          case 'r':
            $('span#output').html(val / 1.8);
            break;
        }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="widget">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select a Unit to Convert to Kelvin: </legend>
    <label for="fRadio">Fahrenheit</label>
    <input id="fRadio" class="listener" type="radio" name="unit" value="f">
    <label for="cRadio">Celsius</label>
    <input id="cRadio" class="listener" type="radio" name="unit" value="c">
    <label for="rRadio">Rankine</label>
    <input id="rRadio" class="listener" type="radio" name="unit" value="r">
  </fieldset>
</div>
<h2>Temperature Converter</h2>
<p>Type a value in the Fahrenheit field to convert the value to Kelvin:</p>

<p>
  <label>Temperature</label>
  <input id="temp" class="listener" type="number" value="32">
</p>
<p>Kelvin: <span id="output"></span></p>
```

My guess is I'm making a pretty dumb small mistake, but I can't seem to figure it out. Thanks for any and all help, suggestions, and solutions.

Comment: Is `.checkboxradio()` a plugin? It's causing an error when I try to run your code.

Comment: yes - https://jqueryui.com/checkboxradio/

Comment: `var name = $(this).attr("name");` The input doesn't have a `name` attribute. What is that supposed to do?

Comment: that was my mistake. i removed the name="temp" from the input field. thanks!

Comment: And what about `switch (val)`? `val` contains the value of the input field, not `f`, `c`, or `r`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two mistakes with your code:

- Forgetting `breaks;` for the parent `switch` statement.
- Forgetting `name="temp"` on the temperature field.

I changed the final temperature to a variable and made that the text of the output just so that there would be so many `$('span#output').html(temperature);`

Also, you should use the `oninput` event to detect a change for the number field.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //$('input[type=radio]').checkboxradio();
  var temp = parseFloat();
  $('input.listener').on('change', updateTemp);
  $('input.listener').on('input', updateTemp);
  
  function updateTemp() {
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    var val = $(this).val();
    var final;
    
    switch (name) {
      case 'unit':
        var temperature = $('input#temp').val();
        switch (val) {
          case 'f':
            final = ((temperature - 32) / 1.8) + 273.15;
            break;
          case 'c':
            final = temperature + 273.15;
            break;
          case 'r':
            final = temperature / 1.8;
            break;
        }
      break;
      case 'temp':
        var u = $('input[name=unit]:checked').val();
        switch (u) {
          case 'f':
            final = ((val - 32) / 1.8) + 273.15;
            break;
          case 'c':
            final = val + 273.15;
            break;
          case 'r':
            final = val / 1.8;
            break;
        }
      break;
    }
    $("#output").text(final);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="widget">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select a Unit to Convert to Kelvin: </legend>
    <label for="fRadio">Fahrenheit</label>
    <input id="fRadio" class="listener" type="radio" name="unit" value="f">
    <label for="cRadio">Celsius</label>
    <input id="cRadio" class="listener" type="radio" name="unit" value="c">
    <label for="rRadio">Rankine</label>
    <input id="rRadio" class="listener" type="radio" name="unit" value="r">
  </fieldset>
</div>
<h2>Temperature Converter</h2>
<p>Type a value in the Fahrenheit field to convert the value to Kelvin:</p>

<p>
  <label>Temperature</label>
  <input id="temp" class="listener" type="number" name="temp" value="32">
</p>
<p>Kelvin: <span id="output"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set one of the radio buttons as default with checked="checked". Then try following:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input.listener').change(function () {
          if ($(this).attr("type") == 'radio') {
            //radio button changed
            var u = $(this).val();
          } else {
            var u = $("input[type='radio']:checked").val();
          }
          var temperature = $('#temp').val();

          switch (u) {
            case 'f':
              $('span#output').html(((temperature - 32) / 1.8) + 273.15);
              break;
            case 'c':
              $('span#output').html(temperature + 273.15);
              break;
            case 'r':
              $('span#output').html(temperature / 1.8);
              break;
          }
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have `break;` after

```
case 'unit':
```

and when `var name = "temp"`

```
var val = $(this).val();
```

the value of `var val` above would be a number in string format, so when you do `val + something` in `case 'temp'` the number is getting appended instead getting added or substracted. Use parseInt(val) to convert the value of input box to integer in case of `'temp'`.